# Create new lines after comma in spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have 2 sheets on google sheets/excel, I'm attempting to create a new line after each comma (if one is present), so it's easier to see. I've tried using regexreplace and substitute but I just can't get it to work. It just throws back an error.

The formula I currently have is - [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXrf4.png)

I'm trying to fetch the data from here [fetch data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twFk9.png)

Answer (score 0):

The formula you specify in your question is:

`=VLOOKUP(B5,'tracking-feb'!A:F,4,FALSE) & =REGEXREPLACE('tracking-feb'!D2:D55,",",CHAR(10))`

There are a few issues here:

1. Excel does not have a *worksheet function* called `REGEXPREPLACE()` though Google Sheets does. You may be able to find add-ins which provide Excel with the same functionality or you can construct your own as a *user defined function* in VBA - see [this article](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-regex-formulas/#:%7E:text=Excel%20Regex%20Replace%20function%20The%20RegExpReplace%20function%20replaces,you%20specify.%20RegExpReplace%20%28text%2C%20pattern%2C%20replacement%2C%20%5Binstance_num%5D%2C%20%5Bmatch_case%5D%29) for a starting point.
2. The equals sign is used to signify that content placed in a worksheet cell is to be treated as a *formula*. It is **not** placed in front of every *worksheet function* (such as `VLOOKUP()`, `SUM()` and `IF()`) contained in a *formula* and doing so will  cause an error in Excel.
3. The *ampersand* sign `&` in a *formula* is an *operator* that concatenates (or joins together) two text expressions eg `="ABC"&"DEF"` yields the text `"ABCDEF"`. Your formula (once the second erroneous equals sign is removed) is attempting to concatenate the results of `VLOOKUP(B5,'tracking-feb'!A:F,4,FALSE)` and `REGEXREPLACE('tracking-feb'!D2:D55,",",CHAR(10))`. I suspect that what you are really trying to do is convert any comma characters in `VLOOKUP(B5,'tracking-feb'!A:F,4,FALSE)` into `CHAR(10)` characters.

If 3., above is correct then the expression to use is

`=REGEXREPLACE(VLOOKUP(B5,'tracking-feb'!A:F,4,FALSE),",",CHAR(10))`

In Excel, assuming you solve the problem with `REGEXREPLACE()`, cells will need to be formatted with the "Wrap text" attribute switched on to display `CHAR(10)` as a newline character (Format Cells...>Alignment Tab>Wrap text checkbox checked).